# vb.net string replace aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string, replace

Trying to replace a string when a user clicks a button. Replace has worked so far but can't get it to work this time.

I have a protected variable, tPage in my class which stores a html page.

Basically I have a asp input field like so:

```
<input type='hidden' name='hiredate' style='height:50px; width: 49%; border:0px solid; float:right;' />
```

(please ignore the inline css, it will be removed later)

The page that holds the input is fed into a string variable and accessed later in order to un-hide the input at a later time.

I've tried using the replace function like so:

```
tPage &= "<input type='hidden' name='hiresign'".Replace("'hidden'", "'text'")
```

but when the code runs there is no change to the string.

**Edit

I found a solution with your guidance. I changed the code to:

```
tPage = tPage.Replace("<input type='hidden' name='hiresign'", "<input type='text' name='hiresign'")
```

Comment: It's more appropriate to do this with a client side script rather than doing a round-trip to the server just to change a string value. JQuery makes this kind of thing very easy.

Answer (score 0):

`&=` concats a string to another, you want to replace the string:

```
tPage = "<input type='hidden' name='hiresign'".Replace("'hidden'", "'text'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but that just replaces the whole html page text with a single string. I probably haven't worded my question right but the variable basically holds a whole webpage as a string, and I need to replace a single line.

Comment: @user2928010: Ok, but where do you split the _whole webpage_ stored in `tPage` to lines? What you show is that you append text to the existing HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim str = "<input type='hidden' name='hiresign'"
str = str.Replace("'hidden'", "'text'")
tPage &= str
```

The point is &= will concats the string in tPage and because of that you are not getting the replaced values corrctly. You have to first do the Replcae and then assign the value in tPage. Hope this helps.